# Equation of a plane from eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The matrix corresponds to reflection (mirror?) in a plane. Determine the equation of the plane.

$$A=\frac{1}{49}\begin{pmatrix}
41 & 12 & -24\\ 
 12& 31 & 36\\ 
-24 & 36 & -23
\end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues and eigenvectors are $\lambda =\pm 49$ and $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
3\\ 
2\\ 
0
\end{smallmatrix}\right],\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
2\\ 
-3\\ 
6
\end{smallmatrix}\right],\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
-6\\ 
0\\ 
2
\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

How do i choose an arbitrary point on a plane when i don't know it's equation?
How do i get the normal?

Edit:
I've forgot to put 1/49 back inte the eigenvalues, which gives 1 and -1. The eigenvalue 1 gives two eigenvectors, which gives two direction vector. From there all I had to do was to write the equation of the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are three facts. Using them together with what you already have should get you all the way to the end.

If a linear map reflects anything, that corresponds to a negative eigenvalue. An eigenvector corresponding to a negative eigenvalue spans a line that is reflected.

For a symmetric matrix, the eigenspaces corresponding to distinct eigenvalues (say the space corresponding to $\frac{49}6$ and the space corresponding to $-\frac{49}6$) are orthogonal to one another.

A linear map always sends the origin to itself.